# Using ArcPy to find connected features and update attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, connectivity-analysis

I have a map containing Polylines. There are some blank field names. I want to fill them with the name of connected features. How to use python to find the connected features and update the attribute table? My strategy is to read each row of the attribute table and find the field name of corresponding connected feature. If there are multiple connected features, just pick one of them.

I'm fairly new to ArcGIS.

The "connected" here means INTERSECT (A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)

[image]

The following code is what I have so far.

```
import arcpy
my_shp = "Z:\Desktop\example\Export_Output.shp"
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(my_shp)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(my_shp, "new_lyr")
arcpy.AddField_management(my_shp, "NEWFIELD", "TEXT", "", "", "25", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
for row in rows:
    targetRow = row.targetfield
    query = """ "NAME" = '%s'""" % targetRow
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("new_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
    my_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("new_lyr", "INTERSECT", my_shp, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
    ##################
    # unfinished here#
    ##################
    print(targetRow)
    print(THE RETURN NAME)
    #update the NEWFIELD with the return name
    row.NEWFIELD = return_name  #the return name
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row
del rows
```

---

Attribute table

[image]

---

Expected result

For example, The field NAME of FID = 11 is blank and if featcure of FID = 7 is connected to it, then fill the blank NAME with "S32"

[image]

---

[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr71786lhcvnyy3/example.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Please don't just delete and re-ask the same question.  You are welcome to edit to refine and clarify as required, but deleting loses the history of questions/comments others have already made

Comment: ... and must be putting you perilously close to automated question limiting/banning kicking in.  Deleting questions is something that should be done only as a last resort.  Lots of deletions early in the life of an account suggests to the algorithms that a user is not working within the focussed Q&A format of the site.

Comment: To prevent your question being too broad I think it needs to be focussed from `How to use python to find the connected features and update the attribute table?` to `How to use python to find the connected features?`.  You clearly already know how to update the attribute table, so anything in your question about that is distracting to potential answerers and future visitors to the site who might benefit from this Q&A.

Comment: The issue of re-posting deleted questions came up today on Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284628/reposting-deleted-questions  The answer seems relevant to your question, and its deleted predecessors: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284641/215590

Comment: I suggest creating basic model and export it to script, if this IS about scripting. Create layer using definition query name=''. Create another name<>''. Spatial join and transfer name to noname layer. Rerun model until feature count in first layer=0

Comment: I have done something similar to what you said. But I don't know how to get the field NAME (the field name of feature that connected)to update the attribute table. That is what method(function) to get the NAME after INTERSECT operation. Please see missing line in my code.@FelixIP

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: @Midavalo ArcMap. 10.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer uses ArcPy Data Access (arcpy.da)
cursors which were introduced at ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop, and so can only be used in its entirety at that version or later.  It was formulated prior to the asker indicating that they were using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

- project your file, I suggest WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_50N
- keep in mind that your no name line has name = SPACE, i.e. ' '

Input:

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
sj=r"in_memory\sj"
infc=r"c:\felix_data\projected.shp"
noName,withName="noname","withname"
empty="''"
while True:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(infc, noName,'"NAME"=%s' %empty)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(infc, withName,'"NAME"<>%s' %empty)
    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(noName,withName,sj,"JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE","KEEP_COMMON")
    result=arcpy.GetCount_management(sj)
    nF=int(result.getOutput(0))
    if nF==0:break
    aDict={}
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sj,("REC","NAME_1")) as cursor:
        for rec,name in cursor:aDict[rec]=name
    updates=0
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc,("REC","NAME")) as cursor:
        for rec,name in cursor:
            if rec in aDict:
                cursor.updateRow((rec,aDict[rec]))
                updates+=1
    arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
    arcpy.Delete_management(noName)
    arcpy.Delete_management(withName)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Updated %s" %updates)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: +1 although the OP has just commented that he's using ArcGIS 10.0 so `arcpy.da` won't be available

Comment: I get an error, " for rec,name in cursor:aDict[rec]=name RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist."    Shall I add two fields "REC" and "NAME_1" before run the code?

Comment: I used your data and it works, I have no clue how you change it, thus no advice

Comment: @Midavalo error message, see his her comment above tells different story, not missing da module

Comment: It is missing da module before update ArcGis @FelixIP

Comment: @XJ.C Please do not edit this answer because those edits have been flagged as inappropriate and I agree that your edits to this answer are not helping to get your question answered.  Editing an answer is OK to do in some circumstances but if the poster of that answer does not see an edit being helpful and rolls it back then I think you should accept that.  In any event, when answerers willing to help you with this question seem to be few I think you should try to avoid doing anything that makes them less inclined to help.

Comment: @XJ.C If you are unclear what an answer means then by all means use comments to ask for clarifications, but be aware that all users are volunteering their time here and are under no obligation to respond to them.  If you have a new question arising out of an answer then you can always ask it as one, but please continue to review the advice offered in the [help] and by users who are trying to help you get your questions answered by spending their time asking you to clarify them where they think clarity is lacking.

Comment: @FelixIP I am moving the comment within your question into this unbolded comment: "I don't like [that] you keep pushing and not showing any efforts of your own"

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using (the very powerful) [Attribute Assistant Add-In](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/).

It has an [Intersecting Feature method](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#intersecting-feature) that copies a value from an intersecting feature in the specified layer.